# <c:if test="${!request.isRequestedSessionIdFromCookie()}"> must be used with a namespace?

Tags: jsp, el

I tried:

```
<c:if test="${!request.isRequestedSessionIdFromCookie()}">
```

in ony of my JSPs since c:url isn't encoding my url's for some reason. (working on that one).
So I wanted to try and check if cookies are enabled with this but I get the error:

> The function
>   isRequestedSessionIdFromCookie must be
>   used with a prefix when a default
>   namespace is not specified

Does anyone know what it means with that? I've frequently used EL with request and I've never gotten this error.

Answer (score 4):

Unless you're on Servlet 3.0 / JSP 2.2, you cannot invoke methods on EL objects like that. You need to treat them the Javabean-way all the way. I.e. do not use `get` or `is` prefixes and also not method parens `()`.

```
<c:if test="${!request.requestedSessionIdFromCookie}">
```

(I assume that `HttpServletRequest` is been placed there, otherwise you've to get it by `PageContext` first)

```
<c:if test="${!pageContext.request.requestedSessionIdFromCookie}">
```

As to the concrete problem of the URL's not being encoded by `c:out`, that tag isn't responsible for that. Aren't you confusing it with `c:url`?